# Why fastboot isn't accepting unlocking code I received from Sony?

Tags: fastboot, android-10, sony-xperia

I'm following this https://www.getdroidtips.com/android-10-q-sony-xperia-x guide about changing ROM of my phone to Android 10. My Xperia X is stuck on Android 8
and isn't getting any further upgrades. It gets only security patches. But that will end soon too.

I got unlocking code from Sony but I got a pushback from fastboot:

running `fastboot -i [received code here]`
resulted in error: `invalid vendor id '[received code here]'`

**Edit:**
I already toggled on OEM unlocking in the system's settings. After running `fastboot flash recovery twrp.img` I got:

```
sending 'recovery' (21824 KB)...
OKAY [  0.697s]
writing 'recovery'...
FAILED (remote: Command not allowed)
finished. total time: 0.699s
```

which hinted me that I needed the unlocking code from Sony.

[image]

How should I proceed ?

Comment: I would prefer the official unlocking guide from Sony: https://developer.sony.com/develop/open-devices/get-started/unlock-bootloader/how-to-unlock-bootloader/ According to them you only need to enable **OEM unlocking** in developer options.

Comment: I did follow the official guide. It is how I got the code for unlocking bootloader. `fastboot -i [code]` isn't in the linked article but I've found thread where another Xperia user used the flag to use the code to unlock the bootloader.

Comment: I added a screenshot to my question.

Comment: That did it ! Unlocked and flashed. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: Funny enough after running `adb reboot recovery` it doesn't reboot into recovery mode. It just reboots and loads into Android.

Comment: Yeah I figured that concealing the unlocking code is super unnecessary. This isn't a security issue. I did it out of habit concealing any authentication codes. :) Even people having my IMEI doesn't really do anything. It's not like you can hack into my phone using the IMEI.